# Using terraform modules for multiple regional api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to create aws infrastructure with 4 regional api gateways with corresponding dynamodb in that region.

I want to create one module consisting of ( API + dynamo ) with configurable region specific values. Is it possible with terraform? Or I would have to create 4 separate API + 4 separate dynamodb resources.

Any links or documentation would be helpful as well.

Currently working for regional API gateway and corresponding dynamodb.

```
    variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  alias  = "us-west-2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "us-east-1" {
  provider = "aws.us-east-1"

  hash_key         = "test_tf"
  name             = "test_tf"
  stream_enabled   = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
  read_capacity    = 1
  write_capacity   = 1

  attribute {
    name = "test_tf"
    type = "S"
  }

}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "us-west-2" {
  provider = "aws.us-west-2"

  hash_key         = "test_tf"
  name             = "test_tf"
  stream_enabled   = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
  read_capacity    = 1
  write_capacity   = 1

  attribute {
    name = "test_tf"
    type = "S"
  }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_global_table" "test_tf" {
  depends_on = ["aws_dynamodb_table.us-east-1", "aws_dynamodb_table.us-west-2"]
  provider   = "aws.us-east-1"

  name = "test_tf"

  replica {
    region_name = "us-east-1"
  }

  replica {
    region_name = "us-west-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "test-us-east-1" {
  name        = "test-us-east-1"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "sample_test" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "{testid}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "sample_get" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.sample_test.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "Deployment" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_api_gateway_method.sample_get"]
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  stage_name  = "test"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "test" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.sample_test.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.sample_get.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type        = "AWS"
  uri         = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:dynamodb:action/GetItem"
  credentials = "${aws_iam_role.apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole.arn}"
  passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES"

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
    {     
      "TableName": "test_tf",     
      "Key": 
      {         
        "test_tf": 
          {             
            "S": "$input.params('testid')"         
            }     
        } 
    }
    EOF
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
  name = "api_dbaccess_policy"
  policy = "${file("api-dynamodb-policy.json")}"

  depends_on = [ 
    "aws_dynamodb_table.us-east-1"
  ]
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole" {
  name = "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole"
  assume_role_policy = "${file("assume-role-policy.json")}"
  depends_on = [ 
    "aws_dynamodb_table.us-east-1"
  ]
}
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "api-dbaccess-policy-attach" {
  name       = "api-dbaccess-policy-attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole.name}"]
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.api_dbaccess_policy.arn}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "200" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.sample_test.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.sample_get.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "us-east-1-response" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-us-east-1.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.sample_test.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.sample_get.http_method}"
  status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.200.status_code}"

  response_templates = {
      "application/json" = <<EOF
      {     
        #set($sampletest = $input.path('Item.test_tf.S'))
        "test": #if ($sampletest && $sampletest != '')
                      true
                    #else
                      false
                    #end       
      }
      EOF
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds absolutely like a use case for Terraform modules. Not sure, where you are struggling. Just start a module that defines everything that you need (or start with a small example first..) and make the things that differ accessible via variables..

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and point out where you're struggling to achieve something or running into any errors?

Comment: right now I have global dynamodb configured with one regional API gateway on `us-east-1` region

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Updated code.

Comment: @StephenKing i updated with code. I am confused how to organize code in modules given multi regional db with corresponding api gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Terraform.

In the root module you define 4 AWS providers, giving alias to each one:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "oregon"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "virginia"
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Then, when you instantiate your modules, instead of relying on provider inheritance you pass the provider explicitly by alias:

```
module "api_gateway" {
  source    = "./api_gateway"
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.oregon"
  }
}
```

Rinse and repeat 4 times for each region.

You can find the docs here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html

Comment: thank you so much for the link. I am still little confused with how to create template module with dynamo dba and apigateway and jsut pass in providers. I have posted my existing infrastructure code if you could provide your inputs thats would be awesome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you put the regional table into the module. Do not declare any providers in the module. Then when you instantiate the child module in the root module (4 times), you pass the provider by alias. You then put the global table in the root module.