# Replicate infrastructure using Terraform module throws error for same name IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created basic infrastructure as below and I'm trying to see if modules works for me to replicate infrastructure on AWS using Terraform.

```
variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

variable "company" {}

module "test1" {
  source = "./modules"
}

module "test2" {
  source = "./modules"
}
```

And my module is as follows:

```
 resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
   name = "lambda_dbaccess_policy"
   policy = "${file("${path.module}/api-dynamodb-policy.json")}"
 }
```

But somehow when I use same module in my `main.tf` it is giving me an error for same named resource policy. How should I handle such a scenario?

I want to use same main.tf for prod/stage/dev environment. How do I achieve it?

My actual module looks like [the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134830/using-terraform-modules-for-multiple-regional-api-gateway).

How do I make use of modules and be able to name module resources dynamically? e.g. `stage_iam_policy` / `prod_iam_policy` etc. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're naming the IAM policy the same regardless of where you use the module. With IAM policies they are uniquely identified by their name rather than some random ID (such as EC2 instances which are identified as `i-...`) so you can't have 2 IAM policies with the same name in the same AWS account.

Instead you must add some extra uniqueness to the name such as by using a parameter to the module appended to the name with something like this:

```
module "test1" {
  source     = "./modules"
  enviroment = "foo"
}

module "test1" {
  source     = "./modules"
  enviroment = "bar"
}
```

and in your module you'd have the following:

```
variable "enviroment" {}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
  name   = "lambda_dbaccess_policy_${var.enviroment}"
  policy = "${file("${path.module}/api-dynamodb-policy.json")}"
}
```

Alternatively if you don't have some useful thing you can use such as `name` or `environment` etc then you could just straight up use some randomness:

```
resource "random_pet" "random" {}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
  name   = "lambda_dbaccess_policy_${random_pet.random.id}"
  policy = "${file("${path.module}/api-dynamodb-policy.json")}"
}
```

Comment: Ty for your reply. That solved my problem. I was not passing variable on `module` declaration.